# Swift delegate to communicate between uiviewcontroller and uitableviewcontroller

Tags: swift, view, controller, delegates, viewcontroller

I've tried following several tutorials and stackoverflow questions to set up a protocol and delegate between two viewcontrollers to no avail. I'm fairly new to swift, so I'm unsure of what isn't working. I have a main uiviewcontroller and a uitableviewcontroller embedded within it. I need uitableviewcontroller to send information back to its parent. This is what I have in terms of code:

```
//Parent ViewController

class parentViewController: UIViewController, childViewControllerDelegate { 
   func sendMessage(controller: childViewController, text: String) {
      print("Sent message: " + text)
   }
}
```

and

```
//Child ViewController

protocol childViewControllerDelegate: class {
   func sendMessage(controller: childViewController, text: String) 
}

class childViewController: UITableViewController {
   weak var delegate: childViewControllerDelegate?

   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
      if (indexPath.row == 0) {
         delegate?.sendMessage(self, text: "Hello Parent")
      }
   }
}
```

Right now delegate?.sendMessage() is not being executed. I assume that delegate is nil and never set. Some suggestions I've seen says that the delegate must be set in the parent viewcontroller. I have attempted to change my parent viewcontroller to:

```
//Parent ViewController

class parentViewController: UIViewController, childViewControllerDelegate { 
   weak var secondViewController: childViewController!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      secondViewController.delegate = self

   }

   func sendMessage(controller: childViewController, text: String) {
      print("Sent message: " + text)
   }
}
```

This code compiles but has a runtime error of fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: `"I assume"` - why are you assuming anything instead of using the debugger to find out for sure?

Answer (score 1):

```
//Child ViewController

protocol childViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func sendMessage(controller: childViewController, text: String)
}

class childViewController: UITableViewController {
    weak var delegate: childViewControllerDelegate?

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            delegate?.sendMessage(self, text: "Hello Parent")
        }

    }

    func applyDelegate(mainDelegate : childViewControllerDelegate){
        self.delegate = mainDelegate
    }
}


//Parent ViewController

class parentViewController: UIViewController, childViewControllerDelegate {
    weak var secondViewController: childViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        secondViewController.applyDelegate(self)

    }

    func sendMessage(controller: childViewController, text: String) {
        print("Sent message: " + text)
    }
}
```

All looks fine with your delegate communication. Make sure that secondViewController was initialized before you run `secondViewController.delegate = self` it can cause this error.